# how to remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code to remove all `2` and `3` from the array and wanted to have this result:

```
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); // returns [1, 1]
```

but instead the result is:

```
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); // returns [1, 2, 1, 3]
```

This is function code:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var b = a[0];

  for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (b.indexOf(a[i]) !== -1) {
      b.splice(a[i], 1);
    }
  }

  return b;
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var a = args[0];
  var b = args.slice(1);

  for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (b.indexOf(a[i]) !== -1) {
      a.splice(i,1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return a;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: What did you change and why?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`.filters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

`b.filter(el => !a.includes(el));`

Check the complete code below:

```js
function destroyer(a, ...b) {
  a = a.filter(el => !b.includes(el));
  console.log(a);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: If you're aiming for ES6 anyway, just use `function destroyer(a, ...b) {`

Comment: @Bergi correct.. edited!

Answer (score 0):

This approach with `destroyer2()` is much simpler and faster with benchmark

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var b = a.splice(0,1)[0];
  
  b = b.filter(el => !a.includes(el));
  console.log(b);
}

console.time('destroyer1');
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
console.timeEnd('destroyer1');

// This is much faster than the previous example
function destroyer2(inputs, removables) {
  var len = inputs.length;
  while(len--) {
    if(removables.indexOf(inputs[len]) !== -1) {
      inputs.splice(len, 1); // Remove at specific index if found
    }
  }
  return inputs;
}

console.time('destroyer2');
console.log(destroyer2([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3]));
console.timeEnd('destroyer2');
```

Comment: I can't see how you dare to call `destroyer2` "simpler"…

Comment: It's easy to read and understand

Comment: Even ignoring the initialisation of `a`, `b` and `c` (which is suboptimal in both functions), those 6 lines of complicated loop code are *not* easier to read and understand than the declarative one-liner

Comment: How do you say its `suboptimal`? What are your basis?

Comment: Well `function destroyer2(b, c) {`  would obviously be much simpler…

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing out.